# not the group of oracle regular expression

Tags: oracle, regex-negation

I am looking to have a not of regular expression group in oracle regular expression query. Meaning I want to match all patterns that do not match the regular expression group

My String:

```
"G,1 = G"
```

Pattern matching used:

```
([[:alpha:]]+\,*[[:digit:]]*)
```

Current_Output:

```
"grouped(G,-1) = grouped(G)"
```

The Problem: Not the Pattern. Match all expression that does not match

```
([[:alpha:]]+\,*[[:digit:]]*)
```

Required Output for the above expression:

```
"G,-1 group(=) G"
```

Other factors: The `"="` may be any operator `"(+-*=)"`

The Code:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE('G,-1 = G',
                         '([[:alpha:]]+\,*[[:digit:]]*)', 
                        'grouped(\1)') 

                 as  "REGEXP_REPLACE_Concatenation"
FROM dual;
```

I would appreciate if any would help derive a Not in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this pattern :

`REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'([a-zA-Z]+,[0-9]+\s+)([^a-zA-Z0-9])(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)','\1group(\2)\3')`

I have not used Posix regex which you were using for simplicity and used `[a-zA-Z]` for alphabet and `[0-9]` for digits.
`\s*?` represents zero or more space.

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` tries to match your operator, but it may match other than your valid operators, so you may explicitly specify them as `(\+|-|\*|=)` instead if you're sure about all the operators possible.

I have put left hand operand, operator and right hand operator as groups (`\1`),(`\2`) and (`\3`) respectively.

```
SQL>
SQL> with t(s) AS
  2  (
  3    SELECT 'G,1=G'      FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 'AB,13 + H'  FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 'BCD,1 * ID' FROM  DUAL
  6  )
  7  select s,REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'([a-zA-Z]+,[0-9]+\s*?)([^a-zA-Z0-9])(\s*?[a-zA-Z]+)'
  8                           ,'\1group(\2)\3')
  9  as m
 10  FROM t;

S            M
--           --
G,1=G        G,1group(=)G
AB,13 + H    AB,13 group(+) H
BCD,1 * ID   BCD,1 group(*) ID
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00adac0d548a1cb6bb1c8b94441b13fe)

Also, If you do not wish the pattern to be specific before or after the operator and only wish to group the operator, you may use:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'([^\+-\*=]+)(\+|-|\*|=)([^\+-\*=]+)'
                         ,'\1group(\2)\3')`